# How do I properly use shared memory (dev/shm) using Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, kerberos, shared-memory, sidecar

I have created a Kerberos sidecar by using this blog post:

The sidecar can be spun up in Docker and it writes to the Ticket Cache in /dev/shm (shared memory).

Next, I have another application container that I want to read the Ticket Cache so I am trying to use shared memory between the two containers.

I have tried the following:

This starts up the sidecar in detached mode:

```
docker run -d  --ipc=host --name ksidecar ksidecar
```

Next, I start up the application container using the same namespace("Host").

```
docker run --ipc=container:host -p 5000:5000 --name myapp myapi
```

The sidecar does what it supposed to and writes to /dev/shm.

**But**

The app container sees no values at all.

I have experimented with modifying the "-ipc" settings.  The configuration that makes most sense to me is to use **--ipc=shareable** for the sidecar and **--ipc=container:ksidecar** for the app container.  But when I do that I get:

**docker: Error response from daemon: can't join IPC of container 516dcc29a0f421b812380378ecc4f6de0032679319bdea4d2279946f4c3d2be2: non-shareable IPC (hint: use IpcMode:shareable for the donor container.**

Of course, I've done that as you can see.

I'm probably doing something wrong.  But I've done hours of searching and various experiements and I still can't get it to work.

Hopefully, someone out there will have an answer or an example of how they've done shared memory with Docker containers.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Your `myapp` container should be set to use the same IPC Namespace, `host` as the sidecar.

```sh
docker run --ipc=host -p 5000:5000 --name myapp myapi
```

If you wanted your app to share the same namespace as the sidecar you would first need to set the IPC Namespace of the sidecar to `shareable`.

```sh
docker run -d  --ipc=shareable --name ksidecar ksidecar
```

Then use that namespace for your application.

```sh
docker run --ipc=container:ksidecar -p 5000:5000 --name myapp myapi
```